# Can we call two function after each other from a class in python

Tags: python, sqlite, oop

```
class admin():
    query = ''
    table = ''
    def __init__(self):
        constr = sqlite3.connect('meta.db')
        cur = constr.cursor()
        self.cur = cur
    def select(self, table):
        self.table = table
        query = "select * from {table}".format(table=self.table)
        # query = "select * from user"
        result = self.cur.execute(query)
        result = result.fetchall()
        return result
    def orderby(self, field):
        query += "ORDER BY {table}.{field} ASC".format(table=self.table,field=self.field)
        return query
```

This is my code.
what I want is calling a function after another function

```
mydb = admin()
mydb.select('usettable').orderby('id')
```

`mydb` is a contractor for the `admin` class and I want to call two functions of this class after each other.

Comment: You're trying to call `orderby()` AFTER the query has already been done. It's too late to modify the query.

Comment: There are lots of other problems with this, like `select()` doesn't return an `admin` object, so you can't call `orderby()` on the result.

Comment: `query` is a local variable in the `select()` method, you can't assign to it from `orderby()`.

Comment: I guess you are searching after the "decorator" of an function: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators Take a look there :)

Comment: Instead of trying to write your own ORM, I suggest you use something like SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
In [12]: class A:
    ...:     def foo(self, msg):
    ...:         self.msg = msg
    ...:         print(msg)
    ...:         return self
    ...:     def bar(self, name):
    ...:         print(self.msg, name)
In [13]: a = A()
In [14]: a.foo("Hi")                              
Hi
In [15]: a.foo("Hi").bar("Shahriar")
Hi
Hi Shahriar
```

So, in your case, it might be as follows:

```py
class Admin:
    def __init__(self):
        constr = sqlite3.connect('meta.db')
        cur = constr.cursor()
        self.cur = cur
    def select(self, table):
        self.table = table
        self.query = "select * from {}".format(self.table)
        return self
    def orderby(self, field):
        self.query += "ORDER BY {}.{} ASC".format(self.table, field)
        return self
    def execute(self):
        result = self.cur.execute(self.query)
        result = result.fetchall()
        return result
```

Test:

```py
mydb = admin()
mydb.select('usettable').orderby('id').execute()
```